# How can i view a columns entire content in Chrome Dev Tools -> Web SQL Database

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-sql

**Chrome Dev Tools** support querying a **web sql database** but the result is shown in a table that **cuts off strings that are too long with ellipsis** (...)

How can i view the entire columns content? Because of the cutoff a ctrl-a selection + copy does not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clicking three times on the value to select it and copying it seems to be working:

[image: Chrome DevTools - select websql item value]

Comment: that was indeed the solution but it is not done with simple copying, doing this would copy the cut-off-ellipsis

dragging like youve shown here is the right way to do it, weird unintuitive way

Comment: @user3789620 agreed, it's not very intuitive.

Comment: +1 for the animated gif solution. I've found that three clicks then right-click (bringing up context popup) and selecting Copy does work and does not include the ellipsis when pasting into notepad (or whatever). Agreed its non-intuitive.

Comment: Fantastic! You saved my day! I've been struggling with this so long

Comment: Thank you! I had to triple click and keep the mouse button down while pressing Cmd+C to copy.

Comment: This only seems to work when viewing the entire table contents, not when working with query results.